# Discrete Mathematics Logic Based

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For our maths assignment it is heavily Logic based, with some of the questions being quite confusing, such as the one below.

My lecturer has asked the following:

In the 1730’s, the “Grande Loge” of Freemasons in Paris was a
highly secretive society following some rather bizarre rules. Each of the
freemasons in the lodge had shaved one other member. No freemason
in the lodge had ever shaved himself. Furthermore, no freemason was
ever shaved by more than one member of the lodge. There was one
freemason who had never been shaved by any other member of the
lodge. The number and identity of the freemasons in the lodge was
kept secret. One rumour circulating in Paris at that time was that there
were less than a hundred freemasons in the “Grande Loge.” Another
rumour put the number at over a hundred. Which one of the two
rumours is true? Justify your answer.

I have no idea what the answer is and would love a bit of help in solving it thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint. If $S$ is the set of all the freemasons in the lodge then we can define a function $f:S\to S$ as follows. Let $x\in S$ be some member then we define $f(x)$ to be the member that $x$ has shaved.

This defines a function since every member has shaved another. But since no member has been shaved by more than one member this function is also injective. However there is a member who hasn't been shaven by anyone so this function is not surjective. This tells you something about the size of S.

The answer is fairly absurd though.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Let $F_0$ be the freemason who had never been shaved by any other member of the lodge. Given a freemason $F_n$ in the lodge, let $F_{n+1}$ be the member whom $F_n$ had shaved. If $m\ne n$, can $F_m=F_n$, or must $F_m$ and $F_n$ be different members of the lodge?